# MongoDB - Size of string values inside array

Tags: mongodb

I know that document size can be upto 16 Mega in size as per this [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON%20Document%20Size).

But in one of my requirement, i need to store long string values inside array like below.

```
content: [content1, content2, content3]
```

content1, 2 and 3 are HTML strings. Each one may have 6000 chars max in size including html tags.

Is this right way to do like this? Any disadvantage by this way?

Answer (score 1):

In indexing, there seems to be a bit of a disadvantage:

> Index Key
>
> The total size of an **indexed value must be less than 1024 bytes**. MongoDB will not add that value to an index if it is longer than 1024 bytes.

(From [MongoDB Limits and Thresholds](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/))

#### Other notes

However, even though we are dealing with NoSQL here, I'd still keep database normalization in the back of my mind: if the content is **always** 3 HTML strings, having *different semantics* (like "short lead", "lead", "article", or something like this), I would have them in separate fields.

Comment: @user10 Ok, then your data structure is totally OK.